# .Net Webform ajaxtoolkit combo box search result

Tags: .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using combox webform ajaxtoolkit. When typing the searching text in the textbox, the dropdownlist will come down as well. However, 
I found the results matching the searching text has been scrolled up passing the visible window. I have to use mouse to scroll up in order to see the matching result. For example, if I search "sa.." the current dropdownlist window will show item starting from 'sp...", I need to scroll up to see results for 'sa...'.
It's so weird, all the items matching 'sa...'should be in the current dropdownlist. Anyone has the same problem before?

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ddlCustomerName" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 
AutoCompleteMode ="SuggestAppend"
CaseSensitive="False" 
ItemInsertLocation = "Append"
RenderMode="Inline"   ListItemHoverCssClass="comboBoxItemHover" 
AppendDataBoundItems="True"></ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Comment: can you show the code part?

Comment: I put the code in. I checked on Chrome, Firefox and Edge.I found the problem somethings happen and sometime doesn't happen. Sometime if I zoom in/zoom out, the problem will be fixed.